# How to reconstruct object from information given by PHP print_r()

Tags: php, soap

I after using PHP SoapClient to call a service method, I get return value $result, which when `print_r($result)` gives:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetDataRowResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [FieldValueList] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [FieldValuePair] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Field] => Name
                                    [Value] => Christmas Party
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Field] => Status
                                    [Value] => 3
                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Field] => StartDate
                                    [Value] => 18/12/2009 12:00 AM
                                )

                            [3] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Field] => EndDate
                                    [Value] => 01/01/1900 12:00 AM
                                )

                        )

                )

            [Message] => 
            [Success] => 1
        )

)
```

I want to use the status value to do something, but I don't know how to get to that value. <strike>I tried `$result->GetDataRowResult->FieldValueList->FieldValuePair[1]->Value` and it didn't work, which I sort of expected.</strike> **EDIT**: It did work actually, I had another typo error in the code else where to cause it to go wrong

How do I get to the value I need and is there a better way to recontruct the entire output into a PHP object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
$result->GetDataRowResult->FieldValueList->FieldValuePair->1->Value
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I realised my issue was with another part of my code but it was too late to delete my question. Hope this question goes on to help others.